# Set toolbar text color in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

I've been trying to change the text colour in the toolbar but I'm not getting anywhere, I have tried many answers from stack overflow but either it does not work or the app crashes on this line `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`.

here is the Kotlin activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.title = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.GROUP_NAME)
}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EEEEEE"
tools:context=".ChatActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_messages"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/relativeLayout_message"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Mohsen it is setting the string correctly just the wrong color, its showing as black text, I want white text

Comment: You're using Dark theme in your styles parent right? That's why it's black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change it on all the application you can use styles as explained in the [actionBar styling documentation](http://www.androiddocs.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

On the other hand if you want to customize the action bar depending on the Activity/Fragment/View you are in you should:

- Change your App style to a variant with no action bar for example `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
- Add a Toolbar to your activity layout
- Set that toolbar as the actionBar with `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

With this done, you can reference the toolbar to change text color and fully customize the ActionBar either from the XML or programatically

Answer (score 0):

You say that your app crashes at this line: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`  
but in the `onCreate()` method there is no such line.  
If you do have a toolbar in your activity use this to change its text color:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

or whatever color you prefer.

Comment: I took it out but if it's in it crashes on that line